# Is there a way to retroactively create time/node based UUID in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, cassandra, uuid, timestamp

Most time-based (type 1) UUIDs are created using the current time. I'm migrating a MySQL database to cassandra and would like to create timebased UUIDs for archived items. Can someone provide an example of how type-1 UUIDs are created using past time periods?

Comment: Probably possible, but why? Isn't the only purpose of a UUID to be universally unique, without actually containing any other information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All uuids version 1 are a combination of node identifier (MAC address), timestamp and a random seed.

Yes its possible. The process is reversible.

From [RFC4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) about the timestamp part of UUID version 1 (section 4.1.4):

> "For UUID version 1, this is
>   represented by Coordinated Universal
>   Time (UTC) as a count of
>   100-nanosecond intervals since
>   00:00:00.00, 15 October 1582 (the date
>   of Gregorian reform to the Christian
>   calendar)."

[Basic algorithm (section 4.2.1](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt)) for creating time base UUID (uuid version 1)

Answer (score 0):

This should be the proper way to create UUIDs based on the past time in MySQL, but database reports duplicates:

```
UPDATE table
SET uuid = CONCAT(
  SUBSTRING(LOWER(HEX((CAST( 1000*created_timestamp AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) + (141427 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) * 1000 * 10)), 8, 8),
  '-',
  SUBSTRING(LOWER(HEX((CAST( 1000*created_timestamp AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) + (141427 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) * 1000 * 10)), 4, 4),
  '-',
  SUBSTRING(UUID(), 15, 1),
  SUBSTRING(LOWER(HEX((CAST(1000*created_timestamp AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) + (141427 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) * 1000 * 10)), 1, 3),
  '-',
  SUBSTRING(UUID(), 20, 17))
```

When altering first 5 chars instead of 8 chars it seems to work fine:

```
UPDATE table
SET uuid = CONCAT(
  SUBSTRING(LOWER(HEX((CAST( 1000*created_timestamp AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) + (141427 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) * 1000 * 10)), 8, 5),
  SUBSTRING(UUID(), 6, 3),
  '-',
  SUBSTRING(LOWER(HEX((CAST( 1000*created_timestamp AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) + (141427 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) * 1000 * 10)), 4, 4),
  '-',
  SUBSTRING(UUID(), 15, 1),
  SUBSTRING(LOWER(HEX((CAST( 1000*created_timestamp AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) + (141427 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) * 1000 * 10)), 1, 3),
  '-',
  SUBSTRING(UUID(), 20, 17))
```

To check timestamp of UUIDs you can use:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(
        (CONV(
            CONCAT(
                SUBSTRING(uuid, 16, 3),
                SUBSTRING(uuid, 10, 4),
                SUBSTRING(uuid, 1, 8)
            ), 16, 10)
            DIV 10 DIV 1000 DIV 1000
        )
        -
        (141427 * 24 * 60 * 60)
    ) AS uuid_timestamp
FROM table;
```