# Make unique invoice numbers with mysql and use

Tags: random, unique, invoice

At the moment this is my function to create a random unique invoice number which is stored in a form's hidden field

```
function generate_invoice_number() {
    global $wpdb;
    $lastVisitor = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT visitorID FROM event_visitors_2014 ORDER BY visitorsID DESC LIMIT 1", ARRAY_A);
    $nr_last = $lastVisitor[0]['visitorID']; 
    $nr = 501 + $nr_last;
    $value = sprintf( '%04d', $nr );
    $number = 'LEDEXPO'.date('Y').'-'.uniqid().'-'.$value;      
    return $number; 
}
```

I have a problem when multiple people are using the form at the same time, say 3 people are using the form they all have the same number generate. 
So i added uniqid(), so $value could be duplicated but $number should be unique? Is this correct or is there a better way?

How can i make test function to test this function on uniqueness?

regards

Comment: do you need the unique id before inserting the record.  Usually it is a better idea to have the DB create the unique ID and then the program to reformat it.

Comment: Using UUIDs (uniqid in PHP speak) is a good way to go. UUIDs are designed to be extremely resistant to collisions.

Comment: @user2310289, yes i think before inserting. i need the last 3 numbers to go from 500. I am sending an email on form submit, that's why I also generate a .pdf invoice with the number which is attached to the email.

Comment: @Idrumm, UUID? need to read up on this tx

Comment: @alex You're already using them.  It's just a different term for what `uniqid()` will give you.  EDIT: I WAS WRONG., see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766009/is-there-a-way-to-retroactively-create-time-node-based-uuid-in-php#3766731

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
function generate_invoice_number()
{
global $wpdb;
$lastVisitor = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT visitorID FROM event_visitors_2014 ORDER BY visitorsID DESC LIMIT 1", ARRAY_A);
$nr_last = $lastVisitor[0]['visitorID'] + 1;
$number = date('Ymd') . $nr_last;
return $number; 
}
```

Comment: tx but that's not neccassery as visitorID is auto-increment on mysql side.

Comment: what's the data type of 'visitorID' column ? and what's your logic to create visitorID?

Comment: visitorID is INT and i am using it to create "unique" invoice numbers

Comment: Try this : $number = date('ymdhis').$lastVisitor[0]['visitorID']